# Probability that a 5-card poker hand is a straight

Tags: probability, combinatorics, poker

I'm trying to find the probability that a 5-card poker hand contains 5 numbers in a numerical sequence.

For the first card, there are 52 options. For the second, there are 4 on either side of the first, so you have $\frac{8}{51}$. For the third, there are 3 on either side of the second, so you have $\frac{6}{50}$.

The end result is:

$$P(Straight)= 52\cdot{8\choose 51}\cdot{6\choose50}\cdot{4\choose49}\cdot{2\choose48}=\frac{19968}{5997600}=0.0033$$

Have I done this correctly? What makes me doubtful is the exact answer I've seen evaluates to 0.0039. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have not done that correctly. The conventional calculation you will have seen is $10 \times 4^5 / {52 \choose 5}$ possibly minus a small amount if you do not want to include straight-flushes in which case $10 \times (4^5-4) / {52 \choose 5}$.  The argument is that you have ten possibilities for the top value in a straight (can you see why it is not thirteen or nine?) and then each value can come from any of the four suits

Comment: I think that the comment of @Henry is very well taken, not only in showing the **easy** accurate approach, but indicating that your approach is *very difficult* to use.  For example [1] The first factor should be $\frac{52}{52}$ rather than $52$. [2] You assume that there will be $8$ choices for the 2nd card.  In fact, that is true, only because Ace-5 and 10-Ace are both ok.  But, what if the 1st two cards are Ace-2, in some order.  Then, you do not have $8$ cards for the 3rd factor (which is what you probably intended, you only have $4$ cards (any three).  ...see next comment

Comment: What you tried is the *direct approach* which in a problem like this is often the most challenging.  For what it's worth, *stretched* *intuition* is disproportionately important in Combinatorics/Probability problems.

Answer (score 1):

"Straight" in poker is generally taken to exclude "straight flush" and royal flush"

However, in the body of the question, you have written "5 numbers in a numerical sequence." Taking *this* to be your intention, i.e. 1-2-3-4-5 through 9-10-11-12-13, the computation, ignoring various rules of poker, would just be

$4^5\times 9/\binom{52}{13}$

### *Note*

I have deliberately used numbers 1-13 for illustration to avoid detailed rules for poker, eg under high rules an ace could count as high or low (changing the possible runs of five numbers to $10$), and the question of whether royal flush and straight flush are to be included or not.
I trust you can add these niceties of poker rules, having grasped the basic concept.

Comment: Since an Ace can be a high card or low card, you should have $10$ possible sequences of consecutive numbers.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: I have added a note

Answer (score 0):

There are ${52\choose 5}=2,598,960$ total possible hands.

How many hands contain a straight (including straight flushes)?  Well, first off you'd have to have at least one card card A-10 (assuming Aces can be considered a 1), which can occur in ${10\choose 1}{4\choose 1}=40$ ways.  Then we need to pick one of each of the successive ranks - there are ${4\choose 1}=4$ ways to do this with each rank, so that's $4^4$ total arrangements.  All told then, there are ${10\choose 1}{4\choose1}*{4\choose 1}^4={10\choose 1}{4\choose 1}^5=10,240$ such arrangements.

Probability of a straight:  $\frac{10,240}{2,598,960}\approx 0.0039400.$  This agrees with the probabilities the OP has seen.

If you wanted to exclude straight flushes, you'd just need to calculate how many of those are possible and factor that in.  As we see above, there are ${10\choose 1}{4\choose 1}^5$ possible straights, so then there should just be ${10\choose 1}{4\choose1}^1=40$ possible straight flushes (ie - instead of each card choosing its suit, we just choose one suit and all of the cards must be that).  So we'd say that there are only 10,240-40=10,200 possible straights excluding straight flushes (note that a royal flush is a special type of straight flush, and thus is factored in here).

Thus the probability of a straight that isn't a straight flush would be $\frac{10,200}{2,598,960}\approx 0.0039246$.  This agrees with the value given in:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability